# How can we help our site and community?

Tags: discussion

What are the different ways to help the community and the site?

Answer (score 3):

One thing to do is when you see a cool data set that's not already on this site, ask a question and self-answer with it. This site has a pretty good pagerank and if high-profile data-sets are described here, new people will find the site.

What is useful with this approach is that the text that is used to "ask" about the dataset, and also the text used to "answer" are often similar to what people searching for data use in their internet searches. A self-answer here can act like a pseudo-blog.

Another thing to do is to add links to this site to lists of interesting datasets. For example, lists like this: https://github.com/awesomedata/awesome-public-datasets